# Purpose of some boilerplate code in __main__.py

Tags: python, program-entry-point, pythonpath

I've seen the following code in a couple Python projects, in `__main__.py`. Could someone explain the purpose? Of course it puts the directory containing `__main__.py` at the head of `sys.path`, but why? And why the tests (`__package__ is None and not hasattr(sys, 'frozen')`? Also, in the `sys.path.insert`, why is `os.path.dirname` called twice?

```
import sys

if __package__ is None and not hasattr(sys, 'frozen'):
    # direct call of __main__.py
    import os.path
    path = os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    sys.path.insert(0, os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(path)))
```

Comment: Please [edit] to now use the appropriate filenames

Comment: It's to set the Python project to ensure the proper path is set from I'm assuming is a script directory to the library directory, if they are not using Python packaging.

Comment: Thanks, cricket, for editing my double-underscore names. I'll remember to use back-ticks in the future to escape formatting characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test for `__package__` lets the code run when `package/__main__.py` has been run with a command like `python __main__.py` or `python package/` (naming the file directly or naming the package folder's path), not the more normal way of running the main module of a package `python -m package`. The other check (for `sys.frozen`) tests if the package has been packed up with something like `py2exe` into a single file, rather than being in a normal file system.

What the code does is put the parent folder of the package into `sys.path`. That is, if `__main__.py` is located at `/some/path/to/package/__main__.py`, the code will put `/some/path/to` in `sys.path`. Each call to `dirname` strips off one item off the right side of the path (`"/some/path/to/package/__main__.py"` => `"/some/path/to/package"` => `"/some/path/to"`).

Comment: Thank you. Now the test makes sense. I had not thought of the different ways you might launch the `__main__.py`.

Comment: May I ask a related question: If you have structured your app as an executable package, that is, if it has a `__main__.py` and `__init__.py`, then in `__main__.py` you will have the canonical "if __name__== '__main__'" where you actually start the app. I would not put very much code right there, perhaps a single line to call a "real" main function. But would you define this real main function right in `__main__.py`, or create a new module file for it? Obviously you could put it where ever you wanted, but what is considered "best practices" regarding the location of the real main function?

Answer (score 2):

`os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(path))` - Gets the grand-parent directory (the directory containing the directory of the given `path` variable); this is being added to the system's `PATH` variable.

`os.path.realpath(os.path.abspath(__file__))` - Gets the `realpath` (resolves symbolic linking) of the absolute path of the running file.

Through this method, the project can now execute binary files that are included in that grandparent directory without needing to prefix the binary executable.

Sidenote: Without context of where you see this code, it's hard to give more of an answer as to why its used.

Comment: Technically it's a bit redundant, since realpath and abspath should perform similar functions. In fact, realpath for the `posixpath` module calls abspath, while for `ntpath` realpath is an alias of abspath.

Otherwise, +1.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh Sure, I was just explaining the function, not the implementation

Comment: Fair. Although as to why, a lot of scripts use a "scripts" directory (which can be any name) and then have a library directory. Using two dirnames would then resolve to the main directory, so imports from the library can be resolved without standard Python packaging. It's great for standalone apps, which can be installed via setuptools or without.

(Not 100%, but it's a pretty common use case).

Comment: Ah, thanks, I didn't realize os.path.dirname would strip the last directory name if given a directory (I should have looked it up!), So the nested use of it gets the parent of the parent dir rather than just being a redundant call.